# flutter, ensure the elavated button stay at the bottom of the screen despite streambuilder built a lot of data

Tags: flutter, button, layout, fixed, stream-builder

What im trying to do is showing a list of assignments and have buttons at the bottom to let the user to select which function they want but when the data becomes a lot and my buttons got push below the screen, i was hoping for the buttons to stay on the screen no matter how many data is generated, buttons will not get push down and the button does not block the visuals of the data, i got an image below to show that
[example at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OsWt.png)

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp/assignment/ViewComplete.dart';
import 'ReassignEmployee.dart';
import 'ViewAssigned.dart';
import 'ViewUnassigned.dart';

class assignmentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const assignmentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<assignmentPage> createState() => _assignmentPageState();
}
class _assignmentPageState extends State<assignmentPage> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String searchText = '';
  String id = '';
  CollectionReference allNoteCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Assignment');
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View Assignment'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: searchController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  searchText = value;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search...',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: allNoteCollection.snapshots(),
              builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
                if (streamSnapshot.connectionState ==
                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                documents = streamSnapshot.data!.docs;

                if (searchText.length > 0) {
                  documents = documents.where((element)
                  {
                    return
                      ( element.get('carPlate').toString().
                      toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                          element.get('custName').toString().
                      toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('date').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('employee').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('id').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('payment').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('serviceName').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('status').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('timeEnd').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())||
                          element.get('timeStart').toString().
                          toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())
                      );
                  }).toList();
                }
                return ListView.separated(
                  reverse: true,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: documents.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    id = documents[index]['id'];
                    return ListTile(
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                        onTap: () {
                        },
                        title: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(documents[index]['carPlate']),
                            Text(documents[index]['custName']),
                            Text(documents[index]['date']),
                            Text(documents[index]['employee']),
                            Text(documents[index]['payment']),
                            Text(documents[index]['serviceName']),
                            Text(documents[index]['status']),
                            Text(documents[index]['timeStart']),
                            Text(documents[index]['timeEnd']),
                          ],
                        ),
                        trailing: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                Navigator.push(context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ReassignEmployee(
                                      serviceName: documents[index]['serviceName'],
                                    carPlate: documents[index]['carPlate'],
                                    custName: documents[index]['custName'],
                                      date: documents[index]['date'],
                                      timeStart: documents[index]['timeStart'],
                                      timeEnd: documents[index]['timeEnd'],
                                      payment: documents[index]['payment'],
                                      status: documents[index]['status'],
                                      employee: documents[index]['employee'],
                                      id: documents[index]['id'],
                                    )));
                              },child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewUnassigned(id: id.toString(),)));
              },
              child: Text('Show unassigned'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewAssigned()));
              },
              child: Text('Show assigned'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to do it, hope someone can guide me, really thanks a lot

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, then you should be able to do that using the Stack widget, just position the button on the bottom where u want it with a z-index higher than your assignments.

Comment: but this will block some of the data's visuals, i have to added an image of an example of how i wanted, can you have a look ? like really thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stack` and `Positioned` to pin `buttons` to the bottom of screen, like this:

```
class assignmentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const assignmentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<assignmentPage> createState() => _assignmentPageState();
}

class _assignmentPageState extends State<assignmentPage> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String searchText = '';
  String id = '';
  CollectionReference allNoteCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Assignment');
  List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View Assignment'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: searchController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      searchText = value;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search...',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                ),
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: allNoteCollection.snapshots(),
                  builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
                    if (streamSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    documents = streamSnapshot.data!.docs;

                    if (searchText.length > 0) {
                      documents = documents.where((element) {
                        return (element
                                .get('carPlate')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('custName')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('date')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('employee')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('id')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('payment')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('serviceName')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('status')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('timeEnd')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
                            element
                                .get('timeStart')
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()));
                      }).toList();
                    }
                    return ListView.separated(
                      reverse: true,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: documents.length,
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Divider();
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        id = documents[index]['id'];
                        return ListTile(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                            onTap: () {},
                            title: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(documents[index]['carPlate']),
                                Text(documents[index]['custName']),
                                Text(documents[index]['date']),
                                Text(documents[index]['employee']),
                                Text(documents[index]['payment']),
                                Text(documents[index]['serviceName']),
                                Text(documents[index]['status']),
                                Text(documents[index]['timeStart']),
                                Text(documents[index]['timeEnd']),
                              ],
                            ),
                            trailing: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                ReassignEmployee(
                                                  serviceName: documents[index]
                                                      ['serviceName'],
                                                  carPlate: documents[index]
                                                      ['carPlate'],
                                                  custName: documents[index]
                                                      ['custName'],
                                                  date: documents[index]
                                                      ['date'],
                                                  timeStart: documents[index]
                                                      ['timeStart'],
                                                  timeEnd: documents[index]
                                                      ['timeEnd'],
                                                  payment: documents[index]
                                                      ['payment'],
                                                  status: documents[index]
                                                      ['status'],
                                                  employee: documents[index]
                                                      ['employee'],
                                                  id: documents[index]['id'],
                                                )));
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ));
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ViewUnassigned(
                                    id: id.toString(),
                                  )));
                    },
                    child: Text('Show unassigned'),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ViewAssigned()));
                    },
                    child: Text('Show assigned'),
                  ),
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @LimJiaHong was it what you want?

Comment: i wanted the buttons to not block the visuals of the data and stay at the bottom, this method will block part of the data's visuals, still thanks ya

Comment: you can add bottom padding as much as the two buttons height, in this way the buttons won't bloc the data. @LimJiaHong